Generate workflow in current devops sprint through logic apps
Good afternoon,
I have created a logic app that generates workitem on my devops board everytime a client secret expires. The only part that I do not know how to solve is how to get that workitem or task in my current sprint.
Is there some code I can add, or anything else to make it calculate/generate what the current sprint is.
I've tried looking up on what to do, but couldn't really find anything. I do get it in my workitems overview, but now I just want to have it in my current sprint.


Is there some code I can add, or anything else to make it calculate/generate what the current sprint is.

You can get the current iteration via rest api, $timeframe is set as current:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?$timeframe=current&api-version=7.1-preview.1

In logic app, you can send http request with above rest api url, parse the iteration name to next step for workitem creation.

Thank you this was very helpful, orry for my lack of research but not really experience with logic apps nor how to set up the desired URL, but this helps a lot!
